# SOLVED: Filtering results arrays in react client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, filter, graphql

I'm mapping the data returned from graphql into a react app. I have used .filter() to apply filtration client side, but I cant figure out how to make the filtration dynamic for use input. my current code is like so:
maps the results:

```
  const names = data?.venuesByCountry.filter(deliverFilter).map(v => (
    <>
      <FlexGridItem> 
        <Link href={`${config.frontendUrl}/${v.slug}`}>
          {v.isOrderingAvailable}
          {v.name}
          {v.isOrderingAvailable}
          {v.isPickUpAvailable}
        </Link>
      </FlexGridItem>
    </>
  ))
```

buttons to filter results:

```
    <Button onClick={() => pickUp()}>PICK UP</Button>
    <Button onClick={() => delivery()}>DELIVERY</Button>
```

functions that I hoped would dynamically filter the results:

```
  function delivery(){
    deliverFilter = venuesByCountry => venuesByCountry.isDeliveryAvailable
  }
  function pickUp(){
    deliverFilter = venuesByCountry => venuesByCountry.isPickUpAvailable
  }
```

Appreciate any ideas you guys have :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use component state to keep the current filter function.

```
const [deliverFilter, setDeliverFilter] = useState(() => () => true)

...

function delivery(){
  setDeliverFilter(() => venuesByCountry => venuesByCountry.isDeliveryAvailable)
}
function pickUp(){
  setDeliverFilter(() => venuesByCountry => venuesByCountry.isPickUpAvailable)
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution and I get:
`Unhandled Runtime Error
ReferenceError: setDeliverFilter is not defined`

Comment: @Nicolas did you import `useState` from React package?

Comment: Yeah I've used `import React, { useState } from 'react'`

Comment: Can you create a minimal working example of this component on https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: Updated the answer due to the way the `useState` handles a function passed as an argument: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state

Comment: So the above works fine, however, personally I would refactor it to keep in the state only the name of the property used in filter function.

Comment: further to this, would this work the same?  `let cuisineV = '';
  const [cuisineFilter, setCuisineFilter] = useState(() => () => '')
  function filterC(cuisine: string){
    cuisineV = ${cuisine};
    setCuisineFilter(() => (venuesByCountry: any) => venuesByCountry.venueTypes = {cuisineV})
  }`

Comment: The filter function should return a boolean, not a empty string.
`cuisineV = ${cuisine}; ` - this is not JSX, no need to use ${}
`venuesByCountry.venueTypes = {cuisineV}` - same here

Comment: Sorry i missed the core aspect of the other filter

Comment: `let cuisineV;
  const [cuisineFilter, setCuisineFilter] = useState(() => () => {cuisineV})

  function filterC(cuisine: string){
    cuisineV = {cuisine}
    setCuisineFilter(() => (venuesByCountry: any) => venuesByCountry.venueTypes.contains({cuisine}))
  }`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

**filter Fun**

```js
function delivery(v) {
   return v.isDeliveryAvailable
  }
```

**usage**

```js
...
const names = data?.venuesByCountry.filter(delivery).map(v => (
...
```